# P element stretches nav with responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been putting a website portfolio together for myself and I just got my home page done. I will say this because it pertains to my problem, I put a div after the header which includes my vertical navigation on the right side, a paragraph that I wanted next to the nav and a background image(id=background).I did this because I only wanted the image to cover the space between the header and the bottom of the page. I noticed every time the paragraph(p) went next to the nav, it would push the nav down. I got a tip from a different post to make the position absolute, which worked. I am now trying to make my home page a responsive web page for tablet and mobile and ran into a problem. I changed the nav to horizontal navigation below the header when changing the position of p to absolute, it stretches the nav space.(as you can see if you resize the page). Is there a way I can move the paragraph out of the div but still keep it in the same place on the regular page?

Here is my code:-

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overlock');
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#background {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(images/Untitled-1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  background: rgb(115, 78, 116);
  width: auto;
  padding: 1%;
}
p {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-family: 'Overlock', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-top: 15%;
}
.icon {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
i {
  display: inline;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
footer {
  color: antiquewhite;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.h1 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  color: floralwhite;
  font-size: 300%;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 300px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.name {
  font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
  color: floralwhite;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: normal;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
.stretch {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.stretch:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  background: rgb(91, 56, 29);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: antiquewhite;
}
.stretch:hover:before,
.stretch:focus:before,
.stretch:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
/* ----------- phone ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {}
/* ----------- tablet ----------- */

  

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*changing nav to horizontal postion*/
  nav,
  nav ul,
  nav li,
  nav a {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .stretch {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
    position: static;
    /*    removing nav animation*/
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: none;
    transform-origin: none;
    -webkit-transition-property: none;
    transition-property: none;
    -webkit-transition-duration: none;
    transition-duration: none;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: none;
    transition-timing-function: none;
  }
  .stretch:hover:before,
  .stretch:focus:before,
  .stretch:active:before {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: none;
    transition-timing-function: none;
  }
  #background {
    background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
    width: 100%;
    background-image: none;
  }
  /*trying to get the background to display correctly*/
  body {
    background-image: url(images/Profile_2.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  /*moving the paragraph to the left since image will not display*/
  p {
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-right: 40%;
    font-family: 'Overlock', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <ul class="icon">
      <li class="h1">Tavyon <span class="name">Richardson</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">TavyonRichardson@yahoo.com<i class="material-icons">mail_outline</i>
      </li>
      <li class="list">989-285-5133<i class="material-icons">call</i>
      </li>
      <li class="list">Alma, Michigan<i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div id="background">
    <p><span>Hey!</span>Welcome to my webiste. Here, you can see everything from my life story, to my my recent projects and resume.</p>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="stretch"><a href="">About me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="http://tavyonrichardson.com/projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="http://tavyonrichardson.com/nms_114/blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="">Resume</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im not sure if it's just me but i can only see it being responsive when i inspect the web page. otherwise i dont see it responding to my code.

Comment: Can you please better explain what you are trying to achieve? It's really hard to follow you question. You probably won't see anything happening in your browser as your media queries are based on device widths, rather than browser widths. If you change them to be just `(min-width)` and `(max-width)` then you can see the site respond to them on a desktop: https://jsfiddle.net/apt2353b/

Comment: You can also move your `<p>` to be after the `<nav>` in the dom. When you update your styles in your media query, the text will then appear in the correct order as you remove the `float`. https://jsfiddle.net/apt2353b/1/

Comment: i fixed the media queries in the code so you can see the p element stretching the nav bar. it's not supposed to be that big. it's doing that because the p element is inside the nav. im looking for a solution to take it out but still keep in in the same place on the home page.

Comment: Can you not just give the `<p>` the background color and move it out of the `<nav>`?

Comment: yeah i did, i fixed the problem. i just made the paragraph in the nav display:none, then added a duplicate paragraph that displays when at a smaller screen size that's outside of the nav. so i fixed it myself. but thanks people!